# Login Form Css not applying to html

Tags: html, css, flask

**HTML CODE**

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn">
      <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
          <span class="nav-icon"></span>
      </label>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/" class="Active">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/register" class="Active">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="form">
      <p>Login</p>
      <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button>login</button>
        <p class="message">Not Registerd? <a href="/register">Create an Account</a></p>
      </form>
  
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000000;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-family: calibri;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0px 22px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #dd003f;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px rgba(198, 64, 64, 0.411);
    transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

nav .menu-btn,
.menu-icon {
    display: none;
}


.form{
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 99%;
    max-width: 260px;
    margin: 200px auto 100px;
    padding: 10px 45px 30px 45px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**Python Flask**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/register')
def about():
    return render_template('register.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm creating a login form, but the form's CSS isn't showing up for some reason. The centering of the form on the page is an example of this. The navbar and background, however, were modified as part of the file. For this project, I'm using Flask, but I haven't done much due to the login form not working. Note (I'm calling the CSS file for flask, which is why it's connected differently than standard CSS and HTML)

Comment: Sorry I thought the question was a bit unclear but the navbar works perfectly fine on the page and the CSS is also working for the navbar but for the form, the CSS isn't working

Comment: Not entirely sure what do you mean by CSS is not applying, I have tried copy pasting your html page and place the CSS inside with the `style` tags and they are working completely fine.

Comment: It worked for me also with style tags when I link the sheet it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you double check your `url_for` render matches to the directory of your css file in your project structure?

Comment: I did it does match(Its placed in a static folder, then there's a "CSS" folder inside the static folder, and then the CSS file is called "style.")

Comment: You mentioned that navbar is working correctly right? Then the css must have been imported, it is more likely that the `form` css itself is not working. I will include an answer below for more details, can you try and modify your `styles.css` and see if it works?

Comment: The changes made to the navbar work perfectly fine when importing the CSS file but on the form it doesn't. The form tho does work when I add style tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noted other problems with your CSS though, where you have used flex box for styling. By default, `flex-direction` goes in the row direction, but it seems like you want it in the column direction. If you also want to center everything included `p` tags and the texts, you also need to do `text-align`. I have included all the details in snippet below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000000;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-family: calibri;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 43px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0px 22px;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #dd003f;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 30px rgba(198, 64, 64, 0.411);
    transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

nav .menu-btn,
.menu-icon {
    display: none;
}


.form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 99%;
    max-width: 260px;
    margin: 200px auto 100px;
    padding: 10px 45px 30px 45px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0.5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div.form > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn">
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
      <span class="nav-icon"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/" class="Active">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="/register" class="Active">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="form">
    <p>Login</p>
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not Registered? <a href="/register">Create an Account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```